# Can device token of Push Notification be used as a unique identifier?

Tags: ios

Problem: using UDID is deprecated - we cannot use it anymore.
There are some solutions on the net: generate GUID and store it in the "safe place",  iCloud, IdentifierForVendor starting with iOS6, OpenUID, SecuredID and so on...

Request:
I need to have a unique identifier of the Device to store user data on our server.

Question:
Can I use deviceToken of Push Notification as a unique identifier?

What are the pros and cons of this idea?

- (-) user can disable push notifications
- (+) unique number
- (+) supported in all iOS

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible idea, the token can change if the user changes device or for some other unknown reason.

- The user can have multiple devices
- If the user reinstalls the app they can get an other token
- It's not 100% that the user will keep the same token.

And most important of all: [**You are identifying devices not users!**](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/)

One solution is to generate a UUID and save it in the user keychain where you retrieve it. But this can also be removed if the user clear the device.

You best option is to allow the user to login with an account, which that can create. Then you can combine this with the UUID in the keychain.

Comment: It seems that the only solution is to have my own log-in mechanism

Comment: UUID saved in keychain is not deleted if the user uninstalls the app

Comment: @user1760527 true, but it can be cleared if the user clears the device.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `identifierForVendor`. The `deviceToken` for push notification is unique, but CAN change.

Comment: identifierForVendor can change, too. Apple docs state that uninstalling all Apps from one vendor and then reinstalling will change it.

Comment: Apple's intent is for developers not to be able to uniquely identify devices between different, unrelated applications. So, an uninstall of an application and a subsequent install should be seen by your server as a new device for the user, with a new identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
         The token can change if the user reset the device, for unique device identifying you can use the following code

            float currentVersion = 6.0;
            NSString *udid = nil;
            if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion)
            {
        //below code is taken from the Apple Sample code, to check you can download the files
        https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation
      // OR
        http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/VerificationController.zip (line number 319)

        udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;

            }
            else
            {
        //may cause apple rejection          
        udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;

        //i think we can use the below link for ios5 or below but not sure it may accept or reject
        https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5
            }

//just saw a link which may help you better and have a look at image
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/
```

[image]

**can someone suggest the best way to persist the unique id even after reinstall app, delete app or system restart or system boot or factory reset**

Comment: 1. `identifierForVendor` will also change if the user resets the device. 2. Apple will most likely reject this code 3. If the user updates to iOS6 you are using a different identifier for the same user. I.e. all his data will be gone.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: then wats the solution?

Comment: Apple *will* reject this code. They perform static analysis and any calls to uniqueIdentifier will be flagged and the app rejected. This is done at upload time.

Comment: i dont know the above code will reject in Apple, but when the ios 5 was released at that time i have used the following code for unique device id https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Comment: Friends, what is the suggested solution?

Comment: README section of the package github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5 says: 
** NOTE: this is not going to work under iOS 7 **

Comment: Thanks to @Pradeep: 
the Guide http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/
says that OpenUDID is the best solution to have a unique identifier. 
BUT, please have a look on this blog:
http://blog.appsfire.com/udid-is-dead-openudid-is-deprecated-long-live-advertisingidentifier/